# Eta Invariant of Spherical Space Form 

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Is the eta invariant of spherical space form $\eta(S^3/\Gamma)$ always nonegative?
Can we calculate it with the information of $\Gamma\in SO(4)$ explicitly?

In fact, i need a reference for the calculation of eta invariant. Can some one give me some advice or download the following paper for me? Thank you!

(1) Hitchin, N. J.(4-CAMB)
Einstein metrics and the eta-invariant. (Italian summary) 
Boll. Un. Mat. Ital. B (7) 11 (1997), no. 2, suppl., 95–105.

(2) G.W. Gibbons, C.N. Pope
Index theorem boundary terms for gravitational instantons
Nuclear Physics B Volume 157, Issue 3, 1 October 1979, Pages 377–386.

Email: xuyiyan@math.pku.edu.cn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but for the lens spaces (i.e., $\Gamma$ cyclic), the eta invariant is computed in the [second paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2075856) of Atiyah, Patodi and Singer.  In case you're outside the paywall, you can try Proposition 5.2 in [this eprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602231).

**Edit**

There are formula for the general case in [this Inventiones paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/k41u1r623p776852/) of Peter Gilkey's.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. Possibly it is meant to point to the following paper: _Gilkey, P. B._, [**The eta invariant and the $K$-theory of odd dimensional spherical space forms**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388468), Invent. Math. 76, 421–453 (1984). [Zbl 0547.58032](https://zbmath.org/0547.58032).

Answer (score 3):

See Theorem 5.2 of [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/SC/2000/4/pdf/smf_sem-cong_4_17-33.pdf) of C. Bär for an explicit formula.

The real projective spheres $\mathbb R\mathbb P^n$ with $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ admits two spin structures. Bär shows in Corollary 5.4 that the eta invariant is negative for one of them.

Answer (score 3):

The eta invariant of any locally symmetric space $\Gamma \backslash G/K$ is calculated by Moscovici and Stanton in [Eta invariants of Dirac operators on locally symmetric manifolds](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01388468). They related eta invariant with the conjugation class of $\Gamma$.